# Assigning of dts values to encoded packets

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, mp4, dts

I have a dump of H264-encoded data, which I need to put in mp4 container. I verified the validity of the encoded data by using mp4box utility against it. The mp4 file created by mp4box contained a proper 17 seconds long video. It is interesting that if I try ffmpeg to achieve the same, the resulting video is 34 seconds long and rather crappy (probably ffmpeg tries to decode video and then encode it, which results in the loss of video quality?) Anyway, for my project I can't use command line approach and need to come up wit a programmatic way to embed the data in the mp4 container.

Below is the code I use (I removed error checking for brevity. During execution all the calls succeed):

```
AVFormatContext* pInputFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
avformat_open_input(&pInputFormatContext, "Data.264", NULL, NULL);
avformat_find_stream_info(pInputFormatContext, NULL);
AVRational* pTime_base = &pInputFormatContext->streams[0]->time_base;

int nFrameRate = pInputFormatContext->streams[0]->r_frame_rate.num / pFormatCtx->streams[0]->r_frame_rate.den;
int nWidth = pInputFormatContext->streams[0]->codecpar->width;
int nHeight = pInputFormatContext->streams[0]->codecpar->height;
// nWidth = 1920, nHeight = 1080, nFrameRate = 25

// Create output objects
AVFormatContext* pOutputFormatContext = NULL;
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&pOutputFormatContext, NULL, NULL, "Destination.mp4");

AVCodec* pVideoCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(pOutputFormatContext->oformat->video_codec/*AV_CODEC_ID_264*/);
AVStream* pOutputStream = avformat_new_stream(pOutputFormatContext, NULL);
pOutputStream->id = pOutputFormatContext->nb_streams - 1;
AVCodecContext* pCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(pVideoCodec);

switch (pVideoCodec->type) {
case AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO:
  pCodecContext->codec_id = codec_id;
  pCodecContext->bit_rate = 400000;
  /* Resolution must be a multiple of two. */
  pCodecContext->width = nFrameWidth;
  pCodecContext->height = nFrameHeight;
  /* timebase: This is the fundamental unit of time (in seconds) in terms
  * of which frame timestamps are represented. For fixed-fps content,
  * timebase should be 1/framerate and timestamp increments should be
  * identical to 1. */
  pOutputStream->time_base.num = 1;
  pOutputStream->time_base.den = nFrameRate;
  pCodecContext->time_base = pOutputStream->time_base;
  pCodecContext->gop_size = 12; /* emit one intra frame every twelve frames at most */
  pCodecContext->pix_fmt = STREAM_PIX_FMT;
  break;
default:
  break;
}

/* copy the stream parameters to the muxer */
avcodec_parameters_from_context(pOutputStream->codecpar, pCodecContext);

avio_open(&pOutputFormatContext->pb, "Destination.mp4", AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);

// Start writing
AVDictionary* pDict = NULL;
avformat_write_header(pOutputFormatContext, &pDict);

// Process packets
AVPacket packet;
int64_t nCurrentDts = 0;
int64_t nDuration = 0;
int nReadResult = 0;

while (nReadResult == 0)
{
  nReadResult = av_read_frame(m_pInputFormatContext, &packet);
// At this point, packet.dts == AV_NOPTS_VALUE. 
// The duration field of the packet contains valid data

  packet.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
  nDuration = packet.duration;
  packet.dts = nCurrentDts;
  packet.dts = av_rescale_q(nCurrentDts, pOutputFormatContext->streams[0]->codec->time_base, pOutputFormatContext->streams[0]->time_base);
  av_interleaved_write_frame(pOutputFormatContext, &packet);
  nCurrentDts += nDuration;
  nDuration += packet.duration;
  av_free_packet(&packet);
}

av_write_trailer(pOutputFormatContext);
```

The properties for the *Destination.mp4* file I receive indicate it is about 1 hour long with frame rate 0. I am sure the culprit is in the way I calculate dts values for each packet and use av_rescale_q(), but I do not have sufficient understanding of the avformat library to figure out the proper way to do it. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you link an mp4 for analysis? (make sure it has public access permission).

Comment: The generated mp4 files are in this dropbox location:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jtc3g6syx8umhri/AAAaTDZFu22vVKSDrYyPLilCa?dl=0

I also put there the source file containing H264-encoded data.

The videos in mp4 files are upside down - it's just the way the camera was installed.

Comment: My latest iteration of code to generate the mp4 file is different somewhat from the original post. I modified the av_rescal_q() logic a little bit. Currently it looks like the following:
    int nReadResult = av_read_frame(m_pInputFormatContext, &packet);
    while (nReadResult == 0)
    {
    . . .
    AVRational f;
    f.num = 1;
    f.den = AV_TIME_BASE; 
    packet.dts = av_rescale_q(nCurrentDts, f, oc->streams[0]->time_base);
    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(oc, &packet);
    . . .
    nReadResult = av_read_frame(m_pInputFormatContext, &packet);
    }

Comment: With that code, the generated video is now 47 seconds long (vs 17 seconds if mp4 is generated by mp4box), and the quality is crappy. I do not understand why this particular code works better than my previous attempts :-)

Comment: Is this solved? I only managed to get video to play at correct speed with correct duration. However still bad picture quality, and media players report wrong frame rate (though plays at normal rate).

Comment: No, it is not solved. I probably should have been more precise in describing the video quality I received from mp4box - it's not great, but it's far better than whatever I get from ffmpeg. I would still be interested in your solution using ffmpeg API.